# Sign up using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So i try to create a sign up method using entity framework and c#, this is the method :

```
//Button create new account
    private void BtnSignUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IEnumerable<DriverAcount> list = from a in context.DriverAcounts select a;
        foreach (var Ac in list)
        {
                if (TxBoxNewUserName.Text != Ac.Login)
                {
                    if (TxtBoxPASS1.Text == TxBoxPass.Text)
                    {
                        Ac.Login = TxBoxNewUserName.Text;
                        Ac.Password = TxtBoxPASS1.Text;
                        context.DriverAcounts.Add(Ac);
                        MessageBox.Show("the account is create succefuly");
                        TxBoxNewUserName.Text = "";
                        TxtBoxPASS1.Text = "";
                        TxBoxPass.Text = "";
                        break;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("the two passwords didn't matched");
                    }

                    TxBoxNewUserName.Text = "";
                    TxtBoxPASS1.Text = "";
                    TxBoxPass.Text = "";
                    continue;
                }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("this username is already exist, please choose another one");
                TxBoxNewUserName.Text = "";
                TxtBoxPASS1.Text = "";
                TxBoxPass.Text = "";
                break;
            }

        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

the problem is when i want to add a new user normally it should looking if it exist in database or not, but it didn't do it right, for example if we have two names in DB **name1** and **name2** and into the TextBox we have **name2** it will add the **name2** in DB even if it is already exist.
So plz if someone have an idea i will be very appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at your code again and understand exactly what it's doing - have you attached the debugger and stepped through it? The driver name will always be created on the first iteration of the `foreach` loop if the first name retrieved doesn't match the one in the text box. All the others will be ignored.

You can try this instead. There's no need querying for all the records (like you're doing at the moment) when you only want to check if one already exists.

```
private void BtnSignUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // This performs a case sensitive match on the login name, you'll need to change it if you want to ignore case
    DriverAcount existingAccount = context.DriverAcounts.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Login == TxBoxNewUserName.Text);

    if (existingAccount != null)
    {
            MessageBox.Show("This username already exists, please choose another one.");
    }
    else
    {
            if (TxtBoxPASS1.Text == TxBoxPass.Text)
            {
                    Ac.Login = TxBoxNewUserName.Text;
                    Ac.Password = TxtBoxPASS1.Text;
                    context.DriverAcounts.Add(Ac);

                    // Only need to call this if you've made changes, so I've moved it here
                    context.SaveChanges();

                    MessageBox.Show("The account was created successfully");
            }
            else
            {
                    MessageBox.Show("The two passwords didn't match each other.");
            }
    }

    TxBoxNewUserName.Text = "";
    TxtBoxPASS1.Text = "";
    TxBoxPass.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: Thnx bro u're right i didn't looking good to my code, yes now it working perfectly.